# Update to XSLT file does not appear in XML result

Tags: xml, xslt, data-binding

I apologize if this is a rookie question; I'm just getting my feet wet with this.

I inheritied an .aspx form that includes (among other things) address fields for state and province.  I found that **the state field saves its data just fine, but the province field does not.**

When I dug further, I found that Province was not defined in the .xslt.  I added a province node to the .xslt file.  However, the data is still not saving.  When I checked the XML result, **the newly-added province node is not there.**

To the best of my knowledge (and observation), the process works like this:

1. The form is filled out.
2. The person saves the form (in reality, it does a postback to itself)
3. On postback, the code performs a data bind and saves the XML to a table column.  (I'm not sure what happens between steps 2 and 3; again, I'm still learning this environment.)

I'm not sure what I should check.  So far, I've:

- looked at the corresponding schema (the field is in there)
- examined the xpath in the .aspx file (it is correct)
- checked the back-end VB code to see what happens on postback (all I found was a generic bind statement for the entire form)
- compared the two fields (other than the ID and XPath name, there is no difference)
- rebuilt the solution

Am I missing anything else?  What should I check?

Note: I'm working in VS2012.

Thanks in advance for your help . . .

Comment: One of my colleagues advised me to unpublish and (re)publish my form.  Looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going on.

I was looking for an XML *file*.  Turned out it was saving XML to a *database table*.

Because the table column already had XML data (from an earlier test that I'd run), it was looking in the XML for a node that didn't exist.

I wiped out the XML (in reality, I set the column field = null in SQL) and resubmitted my form.  Lo and behold, the field saved with no problem.